# useState hook: update a state based on another just updated state

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently looking in to React's funtion Component and the useState hook.

```
const [stateA, setStateA] = useState(somevalue)
const [stateB, setStateB] = useState(somevalue)

function onClick(value){
setStateA(stateA => transformedValue) //a is now transformedValue
//Use transformedValue to update state B 
setStateB(...)
}
```

My question is how to use the newly updated stateA(transformedValue) to updateB after that.
So far i could only access the previous value of State A, not the transformedValue.
I know i could calculate transformedValue outside of the setStateA function, then use that to setStateB. But is it the correct way?
I know can also merge stateA and stateB into one State too.
What is the correct approach? Is there another more preferred way?

Comment: I think the best way to do is calculate transformedValue outside and then use it to set both A and B.

Comment: @MonikaMangal Yeah this seems to be the right way. It just seems kinda odd, i don't know if it's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is using `useEffect` as mentioned.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setCounter2(count + 1);
}, [count]);
```

Because of you obsessed with rendering once, try this:

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Renderderd ${count} times`);
  });

  function handleClick() {
    setCount(prevCounter => {
      setDummy(prevCounter + 1);
      return prevCounter + 1;
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>You clicked count {count} times!</div>
      <div>Dummy= {dummy} !</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me for rendering!</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the method setState is asynchronous.

Your stateA won't update immediately when setState is called.

A way to implement this idea is that

to "watch" a stateA by using **useEffect** method to ensure stateA is updated.

code seems like this:

```
   useEffect(()=>{
       setStateB(stateA); // or do anything with updated stateA
    },[stateA]);
```

Comment: Yeah this will work. But it will cause two renders. The first render occur after setStateA, then useEffect watch for stateA change and then setStateB, which render the component again.